# Twitter Authenticate issue

Tags: laravel, twitter

I got this error when try to authenticate my Twitter account.

[image]

My key and secret are right. I use the League package. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem.The problem is in the version of package league.The problem in version 1.9. I set to version 1.8.